# Change one element each time and get all possible states

Tags: python, numpy, collections

I have one entry [0, 0, 0, 0].

Each element of the `entry` has three possible values 0, 1, 2.

We can only change one value each time. For example, one of the possible state is [1, 0, 0, 0].

I want to get all possible states.

I solved this by the following code. Can anyone provide a more concise code? Thanks a lot!

```
entry  = [0, 0, 0, 0]
state = set([0,1,2])
result = []
import copy

for i in range(len(entry)):
    for ele in state - set([entry[i]]):
        entry_c  = copy.deepcopy(entry)
        entry_c[i] = ele
        result.append(entry_c)
```

The result:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Comment: I don't see why your result should be have 8 entries. It seems to be that there are 3 choices for each term. Therefore, shouldn't result have 3*3*3*3 = 81 entries?

Comment: The basic state is [0, 0, 0, 0]. We can only change one element from the basic state. The state [1, 1, 1, 1] is not allowed. Because it need to change four elements.@Nachiket

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @archer, I get the following answer.

```py
entry = [0,0,0,0]
state = [0,1,2]
ans = set()
#  replace the value of each position with one of all possible states
for i in range(len(entry)):
    for ele in state:
        tmp = entry[:i] + [ele] + entry[i+1:]
        ans.add(tuple(tmp))

print(ans)
print(ans - set([tuple(entry)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use itertools.permutations:

```
import itertools
list(set([i for i in itertools.permutations([0,0,0,1])]))+list(set([i for i in itertools.permutations([0,0,0,2])])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 2, 0), (2, 0, 0, 0)]
```

A more generic solution for any entry and any state is this:

```
[entry[:i]+[state[k]]+entry[i+1:] for i in range(len(entry)) for k in state]
```

An example with its output:

```
entry=[2,3,5,7]
state=[0,1,2]
output--> [[0, 3, 5, 7], [2, 0, 5, 7], [2, 3, 0, 7], [2, 3, 5, 0], [1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 1, 5, 7], [2, 3, 1, 7], [2, 3, 5, 1], [2, 3, 5, 7], [2, 2, 5, 7], [2, 3, 2, 7], [2, 3, 5, 2]]
```

Comment: If the basic state is [1, 0, 0, 0], This method doesn't work. Because we can get some possible states, such as [1, 1, 0, 0].

Comment: I added a more generic solution that works with any entry and any state lists

Comment: The element of entry can only be from the state. 3,5,7 are not in state.